# "Snatching & preserving" versions of a file which gets overwritten repeatedly

Tags: logging, log-files, versioning, overwrite

On a system I'm working on, there are several processes which occasionally write a certain file (we can think about it as a sort of a log, although it's not quite that). Unfortunately, they all write to the *same* output file, i.e. they overwrite it; and I can't control this behavior of theirs. Let's assume for the sake of discussion that the writes are disjoint and there are no races; and even that there's at least a bit of time between writes so that something can be done with the file.

Now, I want to maintain all the versions, for lack of a better word, of this file. In essence I want to "snatch" a copy whenever a write has occured, and save it elsewhere with a reasonable extra identifier (e.g. the time the write started, or the version index or what-not).

First, I was wondering if this is a common system administration task, or something esoteric. It's a bit reminiscent of log rotation, but isn't quite the same thing, since logs get appended to. Still, the snatching-and-maintaining earlier versions of a file is similar.

Second, and assuming I have to implement this myself - how do I "hook" myself onto the file being opened and closed? I don't want to poll it with `fuser` even 1/nth of a second - that seems excessive. Or - perhaps there's another approach you would recommend to doing this?

Comment: On Linux you could make each process write to a different file using mount namespaces.

Comment: Actually, I have the same problem even with just a single instance of one of these processes.

Answer (score 1):

The hook you are looking for is called [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify).

It's a Linux subsystem designed to monitor filesystem events, introduced about 15 years ago (it's not new).  A good place to start would be the [inotify-tools wiki](https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools/wiki).

Comment: Assuming one of the events one can note is a closure of a file by a process - I think the tools are enough to write a shell script which makes another copy of the file each time a process is done writing to it. So +1.

Comment: Move it as soon as it's opened, the fd keeps pointing to the file regardless of where it is (as long as it's on the same partition) and you're less likely to have another process truncate it.